# use Alamofire to post parameters and download image from webservise in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a web service that I have to post parameters to it and in the response I get image.I used Alamofire.download to do this,but I didn't get the image in the response, Is it the correct way or I have to select another methods of alamofire library?

Comment: Hey did your issue get solved?? I have same issue, but did not get any solution

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Alamofire only supports downloading images through one of two `download` methods just like you posted in your question. Alamofire does not currently have support for response image serializers for data tasks. It is certainly something that the community is interested in building for Alamofire, but it is currently underway and has not yet been completed.

#### Other Options

If you are willing to implement your own response image serializers, you could leverage what I've already completed in this [pull request](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/290).

Additionally, I have been working on an AlamofireImage library that is mostly complete, but we're working on figuring out how it will actually roll out. I don't have a solid grasp on what the actual release date is for that yet. For now, I'd suggest you either continue using download tasks, or add response image serializers to an Alamofire fork, or directly into your app code.

Hope that helps shed some light.

Comment: Hi @user2056962, if this answer is sufficient could you upvote and mark as such?